# How did the solution to this system of equations get a power of n?

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I have been reading up on how to solve problems relating to ideal gases. In a certain example problem in the book, Questions and Problems in school Physics by Tarasov and Tarasova, a system of equations were derived and was solved as shown below:

[image]

*I understand how they got each of those equations but I can't understand how they solved them all(especially how there is suddenly a power of n in the solution). Help?*

PS:- I felt this would be more appropriate in math.stackexchange rather than physics.stackexchange since it is the math that I don't seem to get here. I hope I am not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the $p_{2}$ on the right of the second line is the *same* $p_2$ as on the left of the third line.  Similarly with all others that appear.

So, using the final line and dividing each line by $(V+v)$ we have:

$$\begin{array}{l&l}p_n &= p_{n-1}(\frac{V}{V+v})\\
& = (p_{n-2}(\frac{V}{V+v}))(\frac{V}{V+v})\\
& = ((p_{n-3}(\frac{V}{V+v}))(\frac{V}{V+v}))(\frac{V}{V+v})\\
&\vdots\\
&=p_0 (\frac{V}{V+v})(\frac{V}{V+v})\cdots (\frac{V}{V+v})\\
&=p_0 (\frac{V}{V+v})^n
\end{array}$$

This can be made more formal using an induction proof.

Answer (score 1):

First equation implies $$p_1 = p_0 x, \text{ with } x  = \frac{V}{V+v}.$$

Use second equation to show
$$
p_2 = p_1 x = (p_0 x) x = p_0 x^2
$$
and prove the rest by induction with a similar argument.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply all equations together and get
$$
p_0 p_1 \cdots p_{n-1} V^n = p_1 \cdots p_{n} (V+v)^n
$$
Cancel $p_1 \cdots p_{n-1}$ and get
$$
p_0 V^n = p_{n} (V+v)^n
$$
and so
$$
p_{n} = p_0 \frac{V^n}{(V+v)^n} = p_0 \left(\frac{V}{V+v}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

With basic algebra

$$p_n = \frac{V}{V+v}p_{n-1}$$

Which means that to get to the next term you multiply by:

$$\frac{V}{V+v}$$

If you multiply more than once you have a power.